# View function giving error only on one data.frame

Tags: r, rstudio

This is my first post so I will try to be specific.

I have imported few .csv files and I am trying to combine them together.
When I am inspecting each individual data frame, as I import them, I can open them in RStudio View window and data looks correct.

However once I combine the data frames together using `Master<-do.call("rbind", list(DF1,DF2,DF3,DF4))` and try try to view the Master table i get following massage:

> Error in if (nchar(col_min_c) >= 16 || grepl("e", col_min_c, fixed =
>   TRUE) ||  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

However, when I view all the original data frames I am able to see them with no problem.

If I use `utils::View(Master)` I am able to see the data frame.

So I am not sure where this issue comes from.

These are the package I am running:

- require(data.table)
- require(dplyr)
- require(sqldf)
- require(ggplot2)
- require(stringr)
- require(reshape2)
- require(bit64)

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Hi from RStudio -- looks like you hit a bug in our data viewer. What version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: Can you send us the .Rdata file for analysis? `save(Master, file = "master.Rdata")` -> jonathan@rstudio.com

Comment: Data is a bit sensitive.. Is there something I can do where I don't give you the data?

Comment: same problem here with a very large dataset read from a csv file with fread

Comment: @Bakaburg I found that if I use 'integer64 = "double" ' in my fread statement for the numbers the issue went away.

Comment: uhm, interesting, I'll check it out. Would it decrease the precision of big numbers? I use fread because it interprets well big numbers (and for the speed)

Comment: To be honest it resolved the issue I had and what I needed to do, so I did not bother going further beyond that. But if you get some additional insight, I would love to hear about your approach.

Comment: @Jonathan, did the Rstudio gang ever solve this? We are having the same problem, whenever there is an integer64() in the data.frame (data.table in our case) the viewer (View()) does not work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with integer64 and the View() function not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by transforming my table via:

`Master<-sqldf("SELECT * FROM 'Master'")`

So I hope this helps others in the case they come across a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to view the file if I removed `NA` values from a long numeric column (19 char) on the far left hand side of the table (column 1)